# Unloading a View in Objective-C (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, view

I have a View-based app. The first view that is loaded has a button which loads another view using this code:

```
AddPost *addView = [[AddPost alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddPost" bundle:nil];
addView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:addView animated:YES];
```

What I want to do is provide a button on the view (AddPost) that will let me close it and go back to the original view. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a little strange, but you can actually have addView call:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

From the docs:

"The parent view controller is responsible for dismissing the modal view controller it presented using the presentModalViewController:animated: method. If you call this method on the modal view controller itself, however, the modal view controller automatically forwards the message to its parent view controller."

Answer (score 0):

The answer Conrad gave will work perfectly well. In the name of slightly better encapsulation you could put a delegate protocol on addView and have your first view implement this.

So in the header file for your addView controller:

```
@protocol addViewDelegate <NSObject>
    - (void)addViewRequestDismissal;
@end
```

You will also need an external properly on the addView controller:

```
@property (assign) id<addViewDelegate> delegate;
```

Then make your first view controller implement this, so in it's .h file you should have

```
@interface firstView : NSObject <addViewDelegate> {
}
```

When you instantiate your addView remember to set the delegate:

```
addView.delegate = self;
```

In the addView controller when your button is pressed call back:

```
- (void)buttonPressed {
    [self.delegate addViewRequestDismissal];
}
```

Finally in your first view remember to implement this method

```
- (void)addViewRequestDismissal {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Hope all goes well with this. Post back if you have any further problems :)